# C# DateTime changing to another format

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, datetime, timestamp

Sir/Madam,

I am going to perform Oracle bulk insert but invalid bind parameter Papameters : System.dateTime warns here.

The field of Created Date  is timestamp(0) which 22-MAR-13 08.13.27.000000000 PM is only accpeted format.

but when I trying to convert from string to DateTime as follows:

3/22/2013 8:00:00PM

using the following method:

```
 item.CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime("19-MAR-13 08.13.27 PM");
```

// BELOW IS ORACLE BULK INSERT

```
        using (OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection(myConnectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            using (var copy = new OracleBulkCopy(myConnection))
            {
                copy.DestinationTableName = "T_BQ";
                copy.BulkCopyTimeout = 10;
                copy.BatchSize = 1000;
                var query = from item in list select item;
                var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                dt = ConvertToDataTable(query);
                copy.WriteToServer(dt);
                copy.Dispose();
                copy.Close();
            }
            myConnection.Dispose();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) for custom `datetime` format as:

```
 string strDateStarted = "19-MAR-13 08.13.27 AM";
 DateTime datDateStarted;
 DateTime.TryParseExact(strDateStarted, new string[] { "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss tt" }, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDateStarted);
 Console.WriteLine(datDateStarted);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should using `:` for time separator instead `.`

Try this:

```
item.CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime("19-MAR-13 08:13:27 PM");
```

Comment: Invalid parameter binding
Parameter name: System.DateTime

happens

Comment: @RajuGujarati: post more code in your question especially the code that caused the error.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
dateVariable.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:sstt");
```